# Java War Files designing basic tips required

Tags: java, war

I am not sure about this, but a client of me asked that he had developed the war files from some one and want me to design the interface to his application.

I am new to java and dont know what he meant. He is also not a technical sound person. I also want to test the things on my own system before going to accept his work.

I am a netbeans users.

Any help in this matter will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I also don't know what he meant, and I'm not new to Java. You'll probably need to provide more details.

Comment: I don't really understand. First do you know what is a WAR file? Interface of a war file could mean in a strange way, developping the frontend of the application. Do you hany other information about the technologies/framework used to build this war?

Comment: You are not really sound either. Which interface should you design? The one he is using from his war file? Or one to the code inside of the war file? A war file is just a zip file. Which is supposed to "run" inside of Java web server like tomcat. Your IDE is irrelevant. If you only need to test it, put it into a tomcat and go with a web browser on your tomcat. Read the tomcat docu for that.

Comment: No i am not sure about how the war files are created.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. So what should i need to know to design the interface. Consider it is a bank website, the transactions and other stuff. Should I ask them to send me a sample war file? but in any case I need a sample war file so i can test how they work and what could be the limitations on designing interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If he wants from you to design Graphical User INTERFACE;

A WAR file is a web application archive which includes files to run on a java web server for example; glassfish, tomcat etc. Deploy it on web server and it runs.

You could open WAR files with WinRAR and see css and other gui files like html, js, jsp etc. in there to design just don't touch files under WEB-INF folder, they are not about GUI design.

Comment: I know war files are web archive. I havnt seen the actual war files they have.

Comment: I am not having any war file yet. but may be the client need some security so he is different developers for different parts of the app.

Comment: I think you need to learn more information about what expected from you